# Comparing elements of two lists in jython

Tags: python, arrays, list, iterator, jython

I am EXTREMELY new to coding and have no idea how to efficiently compare the elements in two lists/arrays in jython.  I have one list of length 5 and another of length 0 to infinity.  Elements are not in any kind of order. I want to find the difference between each element of the two lists.  So if list1 = [30, 20, 50, 66, 2] and list2 = [6, 50, 90], I should have 15 outputs (len(list1)*len(list2)).  I know how to go through and compare each element one by one, but I need an efficient way to compare all elements at once.  I think I need some kind of iterator function, but have no idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) on control flows might be helpful.

```
list1 = [30, 20, 50, 66, 2]
list2 = [6, 50, 90]

result = []

for item1 in list1:
    for item2 in list2:
        result.append( item1 - item2 )

print result
#[24, -20, -60, 14, -30, -70, 44, 0, -40, 60, 16, -24, -4, -48, -88]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should do:

```
list_a=[30,20,50,66,2]
list_b=[6,50,90]

for i in list_a:
    for j in list_b:
        #compare here, i am assuming a differnce is the comparision you want to do
        print i-j
```

Comment: Note that the OP already knows "how to go through and compare each element one by one"

Comment: sorry about that, but he still says "I need a iterator function", and yet knows going through each element and comparing them one by one........one can't compare all items at the same time, if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: There's no need to apologize! I was just pointing out that your answer (probably) isn't telling the OP anything new.

Answer (score 0):

I find list comprehensions easier to read:

```
from pprint import pprint
list1 = [30, 20, 50, 66, 2]
list2 = [6, 50, 90]

result = [[ one * two for one in list1] for two in list2]
pprint(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option here with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

compare one by one if they are equal

`print [x==y for x in list2 for y in list1 ]`

*output:*

```
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

and print matching:

`print [ x for x in list2 for y in list1 if x==y ]`

*output:*

```
[50]
```